# eloquent belongsTo determine relation table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables, a `news` table store news, `songs` table store songs, `comments` table store comments, a news can have many comments, and a song can also have many comments, in my `comments` table, I use `item_id`, `item_type` to determine which parent model this comment belongs to. e.g if `item_type='game' and item_id=1` than this comment belongs to `game` table and game id = 1.
Below are my model codes.

song

```
class Song
{
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'item_id', 'id')->where('comments.item_type', '=', Comment::SONG_COMMENT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

news

```
class News
{
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'item_id', 'id')->where('comments.item_type', '=', Comment::NEWS_COMMENT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

comment

```
class Comment
{
    public function song()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Song::class, 'item_id', 'id');
    }
    public function news()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(News::class, 'item_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

It's easy to get comments from `Song` or `News` model, but I don't know how to define the reverse relation, is it possible to define a method in `Comment` Model like:

```
public function item()
{
    if ($this->item_type == Comment::SONG_COMMENT_TYPE) {
        return $this->song();
    } else {
        return $this->news();
    }
}
```

Or maybe I'm thinking in the wrong way, how to use eloquent to determine which table to join on runtime?

Comment: It looks like Laravel has no reverse for polymorph relationship (correct me if I am wrong). I think this solution is good for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen  I'm still on database design stage for my app, Do you have any advices for my problem?

Comment: You need to define a method for each relationship in the `Comment` model as far as I am aware.

Comment: Just rereading your question, looks like you're trying to use polymorphic relations when you say "I use item_id, item_type to determine which parent model this comment belongs" and you're not using the correct methods for polymorphic relations. Look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations and I'll put an answer up soon

Comment: @haakym yeah it's about polymorphic relations, But according to the official doc do I have to split my comments table into 2 tables?

Comment: You shouldn't have to split it into two tables. That's only if you are using polymorphic many-to-many relationship. This only requires a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen I believe you're incorrect - Laravel DOES have a  reverse for polymorphic relationship look at the example in the docs for likes where `Like` is the polymorphic relation with the following code: `$like = App\Like::find(1);` -> retrieves the instance of the polymorphic model `$likeable = $like->likeable;` -> `likeable()` here is the inverse method for the polymorphic relation as stated in the docs: `"The likeable relation on the Like model will return either a Post or Comment instance, depending on which type of model owns the like."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement polymorphic relations I think your DB should look like this:

```
news
    id
    ...

songs
    id
    ...

comments
    id
    commentable_id
    commentable_type
```

Then your relations for each model should look like this:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class News extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the news' comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class Song extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the song's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

Read further here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: thanks, it works for me, I didn't think of building a polymorphic model at first, I thought it's was one to many relation. And I also found a great post http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/01/21/creating-polymorphic-relations-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be using the news model as starting point and joining the comments table with two simple wheres.

An example could look like:

```
// Comment

public function news()
{

    return News::

        select('news.*') // Only select news columns (can be removed)

        ->join('comments', 'news.id', '=', 'item_id') // Join comments table

        ->where('item_type', 'news') // Make sure item type is news

        ->where('comments.id', $this->id) // Get $this as comment

        ->first(); // Return a single result. Maybe this is unnecessary, you
                   // should test it by removing this. I assume when this 
                   // will be removed it will return an array of results, 
                   // and that is not what you want. Right?

}
```

This function will return a single result or NULL.

The same can be done for a song by changing a few names.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your hard work, this solution also works, but the result list will be like "news":NULL, "song": {}, not so elegant than the polymophic one.